# how to create filters in a web site

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am creating a website like snapdeal, jabong etc using php mysql  where they uses sidebar filters no make narrow search as given in this link ""http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-printers-scanners/?q=Type_s%3ALaser%20Printers&FID=checkbox_Type_s%20%3A%20Laser%20Printers#plrty|Type_s:All%20in%20One%20Printers|Brand:HP|Price:2836,16755|Functions_s:Copy^ Print|""

similarly like this i want to create search engine for my website and sidebar filters for narrow search results using php and mysql . But the problem is i dont know how to create those sidebar filters and what logic should be used for creating them in php mysql ....

I have searched everywhere but dint get the logic for this . can anyone give some reference code or link where i can learn how to code for creating filters in php and mysql . If their is some code available can anyone send me the link thanx .

Answer (score 0):

Basically to filter out a list result in a website you need to pass the column or field name of interest to your server side application and change your database query accordingly (using where clause) then return back the result to client and redraw the list. This would be the logic you need.

Comment: Isn't their any reference code or any link where i can get help to understand its logic @Babak T

Comment: Well the source code to implement this logic would be depends on a lot of factors such as your used framework or probably CMS.. but if you looking to learn I would suggest you read about database queries.

Comment: I know the database queries i know which query has to be used but the thing is how to change those queries in a variable and add their info that this filter is been pressed . And then return back to previous query on removing that filter . Many shopping sites are based on this but no reference code is available on google.??